# How to create 1- and 2-dimensional hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am loading data from database and saving it to a constant like this:

```
profession = Hash.new
Profession.all.each do |p|
  profession[p.name] = p.unique_profession
  profession[p.name]['descr'] = p.description # problem
  profession[p.name]['created_at'] = p.created_at # problem
end
```

On the line `profession[p.name]['descr']` occurs this error:

```
undefined method `[]=' for 1:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

I want to use `profession` like:

```
<div>Profession name: <%= profession[p.name] %></div>
<div>Description: <%= profession[p.name]['descr'] %></div>
```

How can I make `profession` work with as one `[name]` and as two `[name][descr]` parameters?

Comment: In order to pass multiple keys, you probably want to have a nested hash. If you want the value hash to return a string for `to_s` call, you have to redefine `Hash#to_s` in some strange, catastrophic way. Otherwise, you can't.

Comment: What type is `p.unique_profession`?

Comment: @ArtOfCode `Fixnum`.

Comment: @sawa Yeah, that's what I was thinking.

Comment: Askers are often corrected when they refer to a "2-dimensional array", as arrays merely have elements, which can themselves be arrays. This, however, is the first time I've seen a reference to a "2-dimensional hash" (or even a 1-dimentional hash). That's a real mind-bender. :-). @sawa, re "...in some strange, catastrophic way.", gotta love it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with an empty hash:

```
{}
```

Then, for every Profession record, you assign `profession[p.name] = p.unique_profession`. Assuming that `unique_profession` is a `Fixnum`, that means you get this:

```
{
  'ProfessionName1' => 1,
  'ProfessionName2' => 2
}
```

and so on.

You can't assign sub-keys to Fixnum - it's not a hash. You might instead want one of the following data structures (I'll follow the structure with the code to create it):

```
{
  'ProfessionName1' => {
    'descr' => 'Description of Profession 1',
    'created_at' => '2016-05-08T22:33:38.093753Z'
  },
  'ProfessionName2' => {
    'descr' => 'Description of Profession 2',
    'created_at' => '2015-04-09T21:23:33.093753Z'
  }
}
```

```
profession = Hash.new
Profession.all.each do |p|
  profession[p.name] = Hash.new
  profession[p.name]['descr'] = p.description
  profession[p.name]['created_at'] = p.created_at
end
```

or simply an array of hashes containing every property:

```
[
  {
    'name' => 'ProfessionName1',
    'descr' => 'Description of Profession 1',
    'created_at' => '2016-05-08T22:33:38.093753Z'
  },
  {
    'name' => 'ProfessionName2',
    'descr' => 'Description of Profession 2',
    'created_at' => '2015-04-09T21:23:33.093753Z'
  }
]
```

```
profession = []
Profession.all.each do |p|
  profession << {
    'name' => p.name,
    'descr' => p.description,
    'created_at' => p.created_at
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use hashes you'll need to store 'unique_profession' into a new key.

```
profession = Hash.new
Profession.all.each do |p|
  profession[p.name] = []
  profession[p.name]['unique'] = p.unique_profession
  profession[p.name]['descr'] = p.description # problem
  profession[p.name]['created_at'] = p.created_at # problem
end
```

Then you can do this (but note the output will be a number, the contents of unique_profession):

```
<div>Profession name: <%= profession[p.name]['unique'] %></div>
<div>Description: <%= profession[p.name]['descr'] %></div>
```

Finally, I'd recommend using symbols instead of strings (as that's the Ruby way):

```
profession = Hash.new
Profession.all.each do |p|
  profession[p.name] = []
  profession[p.name][:unique] = p.unique_profession
  profession[p.name][:descr] = p.description
  profession[p.name][:created_at] = p.created_at
end
```

Then

```
<div>Profession name: <%= profession[p.name][:unique] %></div>
<div>Description: <%= profession[p.name][:descr] %></div>
```

On the other hand you could just store and use the Profession instances directly.

Comment: Thanks @Owen. But is there a way to keep content as in `profession[p.name]` => printing the profession name and also `profession[p.name][:descr]` => printing the profession's description? Which is basically what I am trying to achieve. Working on a big project and everywhere is used `profession[p.name]`, so it would be difficult to override this in the whole application. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just modify the Profession#to_s method to print the name?

`class Profession
...
  def to_s;
    name;
  end;
...
end`